# Prove the function to not be continuous at $z = 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, continuity

$$f(3) = \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{\mathrm{Re}(z)}{|z|} & \text{when $z \neq 0$} \\
  0 & \text{when $z = 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Can someone please explain the concept behind solving such a problem? I can then figure out the solution myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(z)=\frac{\text{Re}(z)}{|z|}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ for $z\ne 0$ and $f=0$ at $z=0$.

Suppose we examine the limit of $f$ as $z \to 0$ along the path $x=y$.

Then, along this path, $$f(z)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ne 0$$

for $z\ne 0$.

Clearly, $f$ is not continuous at $z =0$.

Comment: How is $z\to 0$ the same as $z = 0$?

Comment: They are not the same.  $f=0$ at $z=0$, while the limit $\lim_{z \to 0}f$ actually does not exist.  This can be seen by choosing a path $y=mx$.  Along this path $f=1/\sqrt{1+m^2}$ (for $x\ne 0$), which depends on $m$.  So, as $z \to 0$ along this path $f \to  1/\sqrt{1+m^2}$.  Inasmuch as the limit must be independent of the path, this limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give a sequence $(x_n)_n$ going to $0$ such that $f(x_n)$ does *not* converge to $f(0)=0$. If the function was continuous, then one should have $f(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f(0)$ (i.e., $\lim_n f(x_n) = f(\lim_n x_n)$).

E.g., what should be the limit of $f(\frac1n)$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$? And what *is* the value of $f(\frac1n)$ (for all $n$)?

Comment: please explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly: see above.

Comment: Thank you @Clement. Just going through what you just wrote.

Comment: Still trying. Will ask if any more doubts.